# ACF - How do I exclude posts older than a year from relationship field?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF Pro. I have a filter setup that tells ACF only to show posts that are published.

```
function acf_relationship_filter( $args, $field, $post_id ) {
    $args['post_status'] = array('publish');
    return $args;
}

add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=featured_items', 'acf_relationship_filter', 10, 3);
```

**This works** just fine. However, I'd like to *extend* this function so that only posts made in the last year are shown; older posts should therefore be excluded.

Anyone have ideas on how to do this?

I need to somehow apply the following test in the filter:

```
strtotime( $args['post_date'] ) > strtotime('-365 day');
```

Comparing the result of this on `$args['post_date']` wont work of course because I'd be comparing a boolean result to a date string.

Thanks!

---

**SOULTION:**

I figured this out for anyone who might come across this same requirement.

Simply use `$args['date_query']`.

```
function acf_relationship_filter( $args, $field, $post_id ) {

    $args['post_status'] = array('publish');
    $args['date_query'] = array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime('-1 year')),
        'inclusive' => true
    );

    return $args;

}

add_filter('acf/fields/relationship/query/name=featured_items', 'acf_relationship_filter', 10, 3);
```

This will only show the posts that were made after a year ago from today.

Hope it helps someone out there!

WP Docs on date parameters for WP_Query: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are arguments to `WP_Query`, then you could try the `date_query` input argument:

```
$args['date_query'] = [
    [
        'after'     => '1 year ago', // <-- your strtotime string
        'inclusive' => true,
    ]
];
```

within your callback.

Comment: This led me down the right path to the answer, but wasn't quite the exact working solution. I'll post that in my question. If you'd like to update your answer with what I post I'll accept the answer, since you were on track.

Comment: good to hear you had some progress, but note that the `after`/`before` parameters supports `strtotime` strings, so we shouldn't need the `Y-m-d G:i:s` format  I think  `'1 year ago'` and `'-1 year'` should give the same results @MichaelGiovanniPumo

Comment: Ahh right. Okay cool. Well I'll accept this as an answer then. Thanks for your help!